# Selecting from 1 Table and Updating in Another

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if its possible to combine these two queries into 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(ROUND(cost,2)) AS totalEarned FROM transactions WHERE `USERID` = 55 AND `payout` != 'PAIDOUT';


UPDATE user_table SET currentPayout = $newUpdate WHERE USERID = 55
```

Combining them isn't really the problem.. The problem is that I want to skip the WHERE USERID statement, thus searching through the transactions where the USERID matches for that USERID, then update the currentPayout in the other table (user_table).

But instead of doing it with a for loop in PHP like, "where USERID", I was wondering if MySQL has any functions available for me to utilize?

**Sounds complicated? I know.. It is..**

Let me try to explain it in a different way:

Imagine having a table (lets call it transactions), where you have a bunch of different transactions and whatnot. Now, lets say you want to calculate all the user earnings from that table, i.e. selecting the total cost where the ID matches the user's ID, and updating it in a separate table (user_table).

But instead of doing it with `WHERE USERID = 55`, I was wondering how to rewrite the current query into a query that searches for the users in `user_table` and searching for what the user has earned in `transactions` then updating what the user has earned in `user_table`. (But without having to specify WHERE USERID).

Current Structure:

```
:::Transactions Table:::
ID,
UserID,
Cost

:::User Table:::
ID,
UserID,
currentPayout
```

So.. Basically a script or something that searches in Transactions table and updates each user currentPayout.

Hope this makes sense.. If not, let me know and I'll rewrite the whole thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated query with the `UPDATE` statement :

```
UPDATE user_table u 
SET u.currentPayout = (SELECT SUM(ROUND(s.cost,2)) AS totalEarned s
                       FROM transactions s
                       WHERE s.USERID = u.USERID AND s.payout != 'PAIDOUT'
```

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I was looking for!